# How can I serve a domain specific manifest.json for a heroku app with mirrored domains?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app application I am working on that is mirrored on multiple domains. Each domain has its own branding and now that we are supporting PWA app installs, we would like to serve different icons & application names based on which domain the user visits. Unfortunately since the domains all point to the same Heroku instance, I have been unable to come up with a way to set up the manifest file to do this. Is there some heroku settings where I can serve manifest-A to visitors from domain-A and manifest-B for visitors from domain-B? Should we be hosting two applications?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but I ended up switching build packs and writing our own express server to serve our application. I set up the route for /index to string replace a specific dom element with the correct manifest & meta tags needed for pwa compatibility. Here is the route in question:

```
app.get('/index.html', async (req, res) => {
  const indexBuffer = await readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));

  let index = indexBuffer.toString('utf8');
  let manifestConfig = defaultConfig;

  if (req.hostname === 'app.otherHostName.com') {
    manifestConfig = otherHostNameConfig;
  }

  index = index.replace('<link rel="manifest">', manifestConfig);

  return res.send(index);
});
```